# How can I handle POST data in django middleware?

Tags: django

I have Django middleware to handle POST request.

```py
class MyMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, req):
        response = self.get_response(req)

        # want to do something with 'r.body',
        # but it is not able to be read

        return response
```

As the request body is already read in `get_response`, I cannot read it again in middleware.

Tried `copy.copy()`, but no luck since the copied stream references same object of the original one. `copy.deepcopy()` raises an exception.

How can I handle POST data in middleware?

I want to handle all requests, so implementing the logic in every view is not ideal.

Comment: `req.body` or `req.POST` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution

```py
class MyMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, req):
        req.body  # just add this line BEFORE get_response

        response = self.get_response(req)

        return response
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.